# A string acquired through scanf has been muted when it is passed as function's parameter

Tags: c, c-strings

I have taken a string from user input through `scanf` function. Such string is a *constant* parameter of a recursive function named `listlexicographicDepartment`. The latter is invoked immediately after the string's acquisition.

```c
char *dep = malloc(500);
printf("enter the department to search for any courses in it\n");
scanf("%s", dep);
listlexicographicDepartment(dep,temp);
```

Such function is recursive and the stopping condition depends on his second parameter, a node of an AVL tree (the AVL tree is not provided (i) to keep the code sample limited and (ii) because it's irrelevant in this respect). String `dep` never changes throughout the recursive execution:

```c
void listlexicographicDepartment (char *dep, AVLNode t)
{
    printf("%s\n",dep);
    if(t != NULL)
    {
        listlexicographicDepartment(dep, t->Left);
        if(strcmpi(dep, t->Department) == 0)
            printf("%s\n", t->Course);
            listlexicographicDepartment(dep,t->Right);
        }
    }
```

I am observing that my input string has changed when it has been passed to the function.
Input: `French Language`
Output of the recursive function:

```
Language
Language
Language
...
Language
```

Why did the string loose everything before the space?

Comment: My guess is that the problem is because `scanf` with the `%s` format reads *space delimited* input. It can't handle multiple words. Use e.g. `fgets` to read whole lines.

Comment: Also, please don't use `malloc` for fixed-sized arrays, use actual arrays instead.

Comment: If you don't want your string to be changed then pass it as `const char *`. Always pass strings as `const char *`. Only buffers should be passed as `char *buf, size_t len` and always as a pair.

Comment: Putting the code in the question into some skeleton code and executing it with input of “French Language” shows output of “French”, not “Language”. This is to be expected, as `scanf` with `%s` will stop at a space, thus reading “French” and not “Language”. If you got “Language”, there is some other problem in your program. Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Answer (score -1):

Do not use scanf to read strings. Use `fgets` instead:

```
void printReversed(char *str)
{
    if(*str) printReversed(str + 1);
    printf("%c", *str);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *str = malloc(200);
    
    if(str)
    {
        fgets(str, 200, stdin);
        printReversed(str);
    }
    free(str);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/daqbqaf3h

Comment: With `str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;` following `fgets()` to trim the trialing `'\n'`